# What's the book title: woman fleeing from earth, war between liberal colony and earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember the title of a book I've read a few years back. It was about a young woman serving in the military on Earth, who saw something she shouldn't have and had to flee to another planet where other exiled people had created a sort of liberal socialistic society. After a few months (years?) officials on Earth discovered where the woman has been all this time and a war breaks out. I can't really remember the end though.

Oh, and I think every person on Earth is implanted with a sort of tracking device/chip that monitors all their activities.
The cover had some spaceships fighting in the back, and a blond woman holding a gun and running in the foreground.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like "Freehold" by Mike Z. Williamson. It's published by Baen Books. http://baen.com/author_catalog.asp?author=mzwilliamson

Good book, and there are others in the Freehold series. Mike's personal website: http://www.michaelzwilliamson.com/

Comment: wow, that was really fast. you're right - thank you sooo much. i've been looking for ages. :)

Comment: You lucked out, as I happen to know the author and just added this stack to my communities. :) Please remember to also "vote up" my answer (click the up arrow) to indicate it was helpful.

Comment: sorry, haven't got enough reputation but will do as soon as i'm allowed to

Comment: Also, Baen [give away a selection of their ebooks for free](https://www.baenebooks.com/c-1-free-library.aspx), including *Freehold*.

Comment: @evilsoup - I had forgotten Freehold was in the Baen Free Library. Thanks for pointing that out. It's a great way to try out new authors.